# Issue while pasting from MS Word to Rad Editor

Tags: asp.net, ms-word, copy-paste, radeditor

When I copy a content from Ms Word and Paste to Rad Editor it works fine first time by showing a pop up and asking me whether I want to strip formatting. But on subsequent pastes to the same Editor or other RadEditors in the same page requires Pasting twice. (ie: Pressing Ctrl+V twice).

How can I solve this issue. I'm using a very basic RadEditor. nothing fancy. 
Is this a know issue of RadEditor?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the StripFormattingOptions property to "MSWord" and test. If the problem still persists upgrade to the latest and greatest build of the Telerik.Web.UI.dll.

Comment: Setting such a property would by default use strip. But that is not the requirement.

Comment: If you want you can complete disable the clipboard content manipulation by setting StripFormattingOptions to NoneSupressCleanMessage. You can find the other available option at http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/cleaningwordformatting/defaultcs.aspx